# How to save Python API request to .txt file

Tags: python, google-docs-api

I'm using Google Docs Python API,specifically the official example [Extract text from a document](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/samples/extract-text)
Everything runs fine, at the end I get the extracted text printed to terminal, resulted from the last bit of code, main func

```
def main():
    """Uses the Docs API to print out the text of a document."""
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(Http())
    docs_service = discovery.build(
        'docs', 'v1', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_DOC)
    doc = docs_service.documents().get(documentId=DOCUMENT_ID).execute()
    doc_content = doc.get('body').get('content')
print(read_strucutural_elements(doc_content))
```

The thing is Im having trouble trying to save that text to a .txt file, getting this error message

> f.write(read_strucutural_elements(doc_content)) UnicodeEncodeError:
>   'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfa' in position 64: ordinal
>   not in range(128)

The return type of the read_structural_elements call and is

```
print(type(read_strucutural_elements(doc_content)))

<type 'unicode'>
```

Any suggestion ?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running the script from the terminal, all you have to do is direct it to write the output to a file using the > operator.  Something like this:

```
python script.py > outfile.txt
```

This will take whatever output is being printed in the terminal and dump it into the specified file instead.

Comment: Does work too, already tried. Thanks "print(read_strucutural_elements(doc_content))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfa' in position 64: ordinal not in range(128)"

Answer (score 0):

That worked too

```
def main():
    """Uses the Docs API to print out the text of a document."""
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(Http())
    docs_service = discovery.build(
        'docs', 'v1', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_DOC)
    doc = docs_service.documents().get(documentId=DOCUMENT_ID).execute()
    doc_content = doc.get('body').get('content')
    text = read_strucutural_elements(doc_content)
    print(text.encode('utf-8'), file=open("output.txt", "a"))
```

Just had to assign read_structural_elements(doc_contet) to a new variable text, then print(if desired) applying a .encode('utf-8') method to it. Finally wrapped a file argument to the print statement to save the “text” content to a file named output.txt

Hope it can help others too.

Cheers!